# How to "Revert the #use_open_file switch" on gitlab for Nuget.Temporary.Package issue?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

We used gitlab-ce 15.3.3,self-mangent.When we upload nuget packages to package registry and run command:

```
nuget push package.nupkg
```

sometimes,there is an error NuGet.Temporary.Package.
Mentioned two solutions in
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/335488

```
 1. Revert the #use_open_file switch
    
 2. Port !64192 (merged) to %14.0
```

Could someone know where is the "#use_open_file switch" configure?
I haven't found this in gitlab.rb configure file.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all attention.
After confirmed with gitlab supporter,i got the offical reply:

```
What you saw on the issue were suggestions for how our dev team could fix this issue – it's not just a configuration change that you could easily apply yourself.
```

Thanks.